# WPF DependencyProperty PropertyChangedCallback is not being invoked by changes to bound source

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

A `DependencyProperty` which is bound to a property in a data context is not having its `PropertyChangedCallback` invoked when the property in the data context is changed.

I have setup a test program to explore this functionality in which I have two classes; one named "DependencyObjectTest" that inherits `DependencyObject` and another named "ViewModelTest" that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

The code of `DependencyObjectTest` is as follows:

```cs
public class DependencyObjectTest : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", 
        typeof(double), typeof(DependencyObjectTest), new PropertyMetadata(0d, ValuePropertyChanged));

    public double Value
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void ValuePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is DependencyObjectTest test && e.NewValue is double value)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        }
    }
}
```

And the code of `ViewModelTest` is as follows:

```cs
public class ViewModelTest : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private double value = 0d;

    public double Value
    {
        get { return value; }
        set
        {
            if (this.value != value)
            {
                this.value = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Value));
            }
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventArgs e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}
```

Here's how I have my binding set up in XAML:

```xml
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModelTest/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Window.Resources>
    <local:DependencyObjectTest x:Key="testObject" Value="{Binding Value}"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

I then have a slider whose Value is bound to `Value` of the data context. This should update the `Value` property of `testObject` but it does not fire the `PropertyChangedCallback` however, when I manually set the binding in the codebehind, it is triggered.

```cs
if (DataContext is ViewModelTest test)
{
    string propName = nameof(test.Value);
    Binding binding = new Binding(propName) { Source = test };

    if (Resources["testObject"] is DependencyObjectTest depTest)
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(depTest, DependencyObjectTest.ValueProperty, binding);
}
```

Is there something that I'm missing in my data binding setup? All help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Try changing your Value binding like this Value="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}"

Comment: @Mike: `DependencyObjectTest` doesn't inherit the `DataContext` when it's defined as a resource. You should add it to the visual tree. What are you actually using it for?

Comment: @mm8 In my actual project, I have a custom control where one of it's properties is an abstract class that implements `DependencyObject`. That class is meant to be inherited to handle how a custom document file is loaded. The control one property called `Source` and it can be loaded from the hard drive, over the network, etc depending on what `Source` is set to. In my project I have the custom source class loading the document from a text string, and I have the bindings set up in Xaml but when I change the text string, the corresponding text property in the custom source class isn't updated.